# toggle control for map layer on google maps v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to allow people to turn on the traffic overlay on a custom map, and while the v3 api allows this, I don't see a way to have it display a proper toggle control for the user to turn it on and off.  I could build one myself, but it really should be in the dropdown under "map" where it currently only offers the "terrain" option.

Is there any way to tell it to add this control, or an easy way to add it to that UI widget?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off the dropdown map control, and substitute it with your own control which has a traffic dropdown as well.